# Why does this scientific journal's LaTeX article template compile correctly on Ubuntu, but not on Windows?

Tags: templates, windows, ubuntu, texworks, white-space

I downloaded the "LaTeX article template" from this page: https://www.rsc.org/journals-books-databases/journal-authors-reviewers/author-tools-services/

I use Ubuntu, but am collaborating with someone who uses Windows. When I try to compile this template in TeXworks on Ubuntu, it works fine, but when they try to compile it in TeXworks on Windows, there is a large white space at the head of the second page and every subsequent page after that. Why is this?

Comment: the difference is highly unlikely to be related to the operating system, but one system probably has an older tex system add `\listfiles` to your preamble and compare the version numbers in the list that this adds at the end of the log.

Comment: When I compile on Ubuntu, it says "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18", and when he compiles on Windows, it says "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20". Could the new version have a bug which is adding the white space? If so, how can he find and install version 1.40.18 on Windows?

Comment: differences due to the tex version are even less likely than differences due to the operating system. Did you add `\listfiles` as I suggested before?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood what \listfiles does. [Here](https://pastebin.com/L4Mip8fQ) is the list of files for my Ubuntu compilation (which works correctly) and [here](https://pastebin.com/bwSLAD8t) is the list of files for my collaborator's Windows compilation (which add white space and shifts the text down and off the page). There are a number of differences in version numbers. But I'm not sure how to deduce which of these files is causing the white space...

Comment: well..  The first version is very old, 2014 versions article class, old versions amsmath, expl3, and (probably  more relevant here geometry. Also the second one includes a bibliography (bbl file) not in the first.  I'd update the ubuntu texlive.

Comment: The problem is, if I bring the ubuntu texlive up to date, that would make *both* operating systems compile the template incorrectly. The old versions are the ones that cause it compile correctly, so ideally I want to find a way to restore the Windows texlive to the old version...

Comment: I wouldn't do that, it would make your document unmaintainable, better to fix the spacing on the current system, and update the old one. (but if you really want that, just copy all the files listed from the ubuntu setup to the local directory with the document on both systems then you will be using the same files.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I found the issue: the latest version of `fancyhdr.sty` has a bug in it which causes the white space, so I just gave my collaborator the older version of that file.

Comment: If you think you found a bug, please report it to Piet van Oostrum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is highly unlikely to be related to the operating system, or differences in the tex binary. One system probably has an older tex system, and so will be using different TeX macros for some functions.

Add `\listfiles` to your preamble and compare the version numbers in the list that this adds at the end of the log.

Generally it is better to simply update the tex systems and then get the desired formatting on the current platform. However an alternative that can be useful sometimes, especially with large existing document working on an older system, is to copy any files showing different versions to the working directory and share them alongside the main document source, so that both systems pick up the same macros.